# How to move to another Screen when clicking on FCM notification with flutter?

Tags: flutter, redirect, push-notification, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I create a method for recieving a notification via FCM on my flutter application. Now after clicking this notification I want to move to another Screen.
this is the code:

```
Future<List<String>> registerForegroundMessageHandler() async {
    Completer<List<String>> completer = Completer<List<String>>();
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((remoteMessage) {
      AppLogger.log(" --- foreground message received ---", "");
      AppLogger.log("Title", remoteMessage.notification!.title);
      AppLogger.log("Body", remoteMessage.notification!.body);
      String smallIcon = 'drawable/small_launcher_icon';
      AndroidNotificationDetails androidNotificationDetails =
          AndroidNotificationDetails('channel_id', 'channel_name',
              importance: Importance.high,
              priority: Priority.high,
              ticker: 'New message received',
              icon: smallIcon,
              playSound: true,
              enableVibration: true,
              styleInformation: const DefaultStyleInformation(true, true),
              //sound: RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound('notification'),
              largeIcon:
                  const DrawableResourceAndroidBitmap('mipmap/launcher_icon'),
              color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 123, 255),
              ledColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 0, 0),
              ledOnMs: 1000,
              ongoing: true,
              ledOffMs: 500);
      NotificationDetails notificationDetails =
          NotificationDetails(android: androidNotificationDetails);
      // Display the notification
      flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
        0, // Notification ID
        remoteMessage.notification?.title ?? 'default title',
        remoteMessage.notification?.body ?? 'default body',
        notificationDetails,
      );
      final version = remoteMessage.data['version'];
      final size = remoteMessage.data['size'];

      AppLogger.log("Version", version);
      if (version != null) {
        AppLogger.log("Version:", version);
        downloadFile.messageHandler(remoteMessage);
      } else {
        AppLogger.log("No version found in message data.", "No");
      }

      completer.complete(['$size', 'Version $version']);
    });
    AppLogger.log("Version2, Size", await completer.future);

    return await completer.future;
  }
```

What's the necessary updates to get the expected result ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `onMessageOpenedApp` to redirect in on tapping the push notification.

```
FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      print('ffffffffffffffffffff');
      print("onMessageOpenedApp: $message");
      Navigator.pushReplacement(NavigationService.navigatorKey.currentContext!, SlideLeftRoute(page: NotificationScreenView()));
    });
```

To redirect app from Kill state you can use `getInitialMessage`  funtion to redirect to specific screen

```
    FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage().then((message) {
      if (Platform.isAndroid){
  if (message != null) {
    RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
    AndroidNotification? android = message.notification?.android;
    if (notification != null && android != null) {
    //  TODO
    //  Do any logic, for example dialog
    Navigator.pushReplacement(NavigationService.navigatorKey.currentContext!, SlideLeftRoute(page: NotificationScreenView()));
    }
  }
      }else{
          if (message != null) {
            appConstants.fromBacground.value = true;
    Navigator.pushReplacement(NavigationService.navigatorKey.currentContext!, SlideLeftRoute(page: NotificationScreenView()));
  }
      }

  
});
```

Comment: I don't understand with what should I replace (NavigationService.navigatorKey.currentContext!

Comment: Replace it with your context @ASMA

Comment: @Minato Worked for me, you saved my whole night. Thanks
  FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage().then((message) {
      if (message != null) {
        _handleNotificationClick(context, message);
      }
    });